# jQuery UI draggable containment with overflow hidden

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable

I have a ul bigger than the wrapper and I want to be able to drag it until the last child (with containment).

I have this code for dragging the ul and work fine (without containment).

```
$( "#myList" ).draggable({ axis: "x" });​
```

Here is the working page: http://jsfiddle.net/Kxtvg/

But I need help trying to restrict the drag, if I use

```
$( "#myList" ).draggable({ axis: "x", containment: '#width' });​
```

It behaves funny... http://jsfiddle.net/Z9UYA/

How can I make the ul drag smoothly, with a hidden overflow wrapper and a with containment div?

THX!

Answer (score 3):

try setting "#width" element's width greater than "#myList" element's width somthing like below.

> #width {width:1200px; height:150px; overflow:hidden;}   #myList
>   {width:600px;height:150px; overflow:hidden;}